# AJW Export download button

Tags: members, freemember, export, sql, csv

I am using the Add-on AJW Export to export member details in CSV format. Each time the page loads the CSV format downloads automatically. Anyone any suggestions how to activate the download via a click rather than on page load..

Code looks like this:

{exp:ajw_export 
    sql="SELECT *
    FROM exp_member_data" 
        format="csv" filename="members.csv"
                            }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<a href="members/index" class="button">Download</a>
```

(place this button anywhere you want)

Just create group in your templates called members and add 
`{exp:ajw_export sql="SELECT * FROM exp_member_data" format="csv" filename="members.csv" }`
to index file.